# http error CORS Node JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I am creating a micro server node JS only using native node http. But only when I do post the form is returned me a cors a error.

Follow the below code I'm writing:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var contatos = [
   {nome: "Bruno", telefone: "9999-2222", data: new Date(), operadora:       {nome: "Oi", codigo: 14, categoria: "Celular"}},
   {nome: "Sandra", telefone: "9999-3333", data: new Date(), operadora:        {nome: "Vivo", codigo: 15, categoria: "Celular"}},
   {nome: "Mariana", telefone: "9999-9999", data: new Date(), operadora:                      {nome: "Tim", codigo: 41, categoria: "Celular"}}
 ];

 var operadoras = [
     {nome: "Oi", codigo: 14, categoria: "Celular", preco: 2},
{nome: "Vivo", codigo: 15, categoria: "Celular", preco: 1},
{nome: "Tim", codigo: 41, categoria: "Celular", preco: 3},
{nome: "GVT", codigo: 25, categoria: "Fixo", preco: 1},
{nome: "Embratel", codigo: 21, categoria: "Fixo", preco: 2}
];

var headers = {};
headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = true;
headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '86400'; // 24 hours
headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
switch(url_parts.pathname) {

case '/contatos':
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
            //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(contatos));
    break;
case '/operadoras':
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(operadoras));
    break;
case '/contatos/inserir':
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
            var queryData = '';
            req.on('data', function(data) {
                queryData += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        var obj = querystring.parse(queryData);
        contatos.push(obj);
    });
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'});
            res.end('Objeto inserido.');
            break;
default:
    res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'});
    res.end('Rota não encontrada');
}
}).listen(3000, function () {
console.log('server run on 3000');
});
```

Follow the instructions below to share angular with http post:

```
$scope.adicionarContato = function(contato) {
      console.log(contato);
      contato.data = new Date();
      $http.post("http://localhost:3000/contatos/inserir", contato).success(function (data) {

      });
      delete $scope.contato;
      $scope.contatoForm.$setPristine();
    };
```

And now the error that is returned in the browser:

```
  Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
  fromJson@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:1252:9
  defaultHttpResponseTransform@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:9414:1
 transformData/<@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:9505:12
forEach@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:336:11
transformData@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:9504:3
transformResponse@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:10276:23
processQueue@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:14745:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@file:///home/tiago/Dropbox/branas_angularjs/lib/angular/angular.js:14761:27
```

$RootScopeProvider/this.$get

This code on gist: https://gist.github.com/tiagoeborsanyi/0d2992c67d4cd57f0db5
If someone can help me, I'm already two days ago caught it. : (
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a CORS error. There's something wrong in the code. Try debugging your angular code with Chrome's developer tools. Also, check your node logs for errors there.

The most common CORS error you will encounter will look like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://some.api/endpoint. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://origin.youre/calling/api/from' is therefore not allowed access.

CORS errors typically list the requested domain and the requesting domain along with an explanation of the error. Learn more about CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score -1):

It is because at your node server you have to allow resource sharing to the client platform.

For better understanding you can refer to the video which resolves the issue within 1 minute.

https://youtu.be/BVwZAr04bkc

Comment: Any external videos should not be mentioned as if it gets removed tomorrow, no one would be able to look for it. So better to summarize the solution/hints/sggestions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33164299)